# DNN - Mange Icon not visible

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have deployed dnn6.2.6

After logging in as admin/host user - when am in any page ( that too in EDIT mode - dropdown ) am not able to see the MANAGE Icon. :(

Is there any  value to be set or enable any setting , in-order to make this facility enable after installing ?

where am missing ?

Please suggest

Rigin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by looking for any javascript errors on the page. It is likely something is throwing a JS error earlier on and killing the icons on modules later in the page.

Do you have a custom skin, or any custom modules being loaded on the page?

Does it function different for an Admin or Host account?

Comment: No. Just I have deployed it. Nothing I have added .
Its same case for both Admin/host account

Comment: Module was not there :)
THanks

Comment: Well that is definitely one cause I will have to keep in mind for future replies :D

Comment: Am new to DNN, found many tutorial in your name

Really helpful. will get in touch again ;)

Answer (score 0):

My issue was :

Site Mgmt > edit site setting <<=== more need to configure site here

&

Add module > add "HTML editor" Module  to that Page

Rigin